# Even though client wrote the data on network stream it is not available on server Why

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

**client side coding**

```
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient("192.157.1.1", 8001);
Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
byte[] bites = new byte[dataLength];
    // assigning values for bites
stm.Write(clientdata, 0, clientdata.Length);
```

**Server side Coding**

```
 TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8001);
 listener.Start(10);
 Socket soc = listener.AcceptSocket();
 byte[] bites = new byte[1000];
 int avail = soc.Available;
 int receivedBytesLen = soc.Receive(bites);
```

After writting the clientdata on stream also  In server side soc.Available is zero. So server can't read the data. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The data is buffered. The client hast to Write more. Or close the stream.

Comment: Closing the stream should work but `NetworkStream.Flush()` does not do anything and is reserved for future use, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush.aspx .

Answer (score 2):

NetworkStream.Flush() is actually not implemented 'yet' in .net 4.0 as per msdn:

> Flushes data from the stream. This method is reserved for future use.

Your problem is probably being caused by the [nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm), prevent small amounts of data being sent to reduce congestion. You could try disabling it by setting the following properties on your tcpClient object:

```
tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
tcpClient.Client.NoDelay = true;
```

Also checkout [networkComms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net) which is a ready to use solution if you keep having problems.

Answer (score -2):

after `stm.Write(...)` add a call `stm.Flush()` so the data will be flushed to the network.

Comment: Flush is not implemented